# Generating automatically the jaxb.index file using maven

Tags: maven, xml-serialization, jaxb, jaxb2

I have a package with multiple java classes inside.
I need to read xml files with the package's classes data.
Is there an automatic way (using maven) to generate the ObjectFactory class or the jaxb.index file from the content of the package?
I'm aware I can initiate the jaxb context with specific classes but this will force me to change the code each time I add a new class.
Thanks in advance,
  Avner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the jaxb2-maven plugin to generate other things. If the classes have the appropriate annotations it shouldn't be a problem.

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.3.1</version>
```

See here: http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/

Comment: I don't think you can use the plug-in to just generate the object factory for java classes already written. If you start from XSD it will generate the java classes and the factory but this isn't my case. If there is an option to run it on a package with existing classes and ask for generating just the factory class please let me know. Thanks, Avner

Comment: First you can create the XSD's from it and from XSD's you can create the code which contains the factories. After that just smash away the rest.

Comment: can it genreate jaxb.index file?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I've chosen to use the API JAXBContext.newInstance which accepts an array of classes. I've written a short wrapper which accepts packages names and scan them using  spring for the relevant classes (based on the XmlRootElement annotation). then I use the above API for creating the jaxb context. Since it is an expensive operation you should consider to cache these contexts (which are thread safe) for future use.

Answer (score 0):

The "easiest" way to do this is using Atteo's class index.
Having this Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.atteo.classindex</groupId>
    <artifactId>classindex</artifactId>
    <version>3.13</version>
</dependency>
```

will add an annotation processor to the build.

Adding `@IndexSubclasses` annotation to the corresponding `package-info.java` will make that annotation processor generate `jaxb.index` file. I.e.:

```java
@XmlSchema(
        namespace = "https://schemas.com/super.xsd",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@IndexSubclasses
package pkg.with.my.schema;

import org.atteo.classindex.IndexSubclasses;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**IMPORTANT** A big drawback for this approach is that Atteo's annotations have RUNTIME retention; therefore, the dependency must be included as a runtime dependency as well as a compile-time one. If you are building a self-contained jar, that would no longer possible with using Atteo's class index, unless you shade or build jar with dependencies.